# Will a destructor be called if it is for an object in a vector?

Tags: c++, memory, destructor

This is an assignment from my course which I am having trouble to understand the reasoning behind.

We have a class Person which has no pointers and a class Car as follows:

```
class Car{
public:
  //stuff
private:
  Person* owner;
};
```

And then a function which is as following:

```
void f() {
  vector<Car> v;
  // do stuff with the vector
}
```

When the function is finished, there is a memory leak, to fix it the course material recommends to go through each Car in the vector and delete the owner pointer at the end of the function f(). Is it not sufficient to simply write a destructor for Car which deletes its owner to prevent the memory leak?

By simply adding this in the Car class:

```
~Car() {
  delete owner;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer!

Comment: Well, it's a bit more involved. If you need to define a destructor, you probably need to pay attention to other [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) as well.

Comment: Yeah I understand that if an objects manages memory it should implement the rule-of-five, it was just that I thought that I perhaps missed something related to destructors.

Comment: Good. Than I'm pleased to inform you, that you are leaps and bounds ahead of the course material (which was probably written by someone not well-versed in c++).

Comment: Off-topic, but a car that kills its owner when it's destroyed wouldn't be a huge success. This suggests that the author of your course material hasn't really thought this through.

Comment: @molbdnilo, may be we are talking about some 'car-taur' of sorts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is certainly not enough. Is your class correctly following rule of 5? I.e. do you have properly defined or deleted copy constructor, assingment operator, move constructor and move assingment? Are you really ready to manage this pointer yourself?

I have two solutions for you.

1. Do not use the pointer at all. From the code it is not clear why you need a pointer to `Person`, rather than the object of type `Person`. Are you calling `Person`s members polymorphically? Use non-pointers unless you have to.
2. If you sure you need a pointer, use a pointer which manages itself. `std::unique_ptr` should be your first stop, and if you are sure shared ownership is required, use `std::shared_ptr`.